# Hide tab bar in NSTabViewController in storyboard

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstabview, nstabviewcontroller

Does anybody know how to hide the tabbar within a `NSTabView`?
There are just iOS versions out there but I need a solution for OSX.

Here is my storyboard:

[image]

I want to hide the tabbar… Where do I have to do it and how do I have to do it?

Comment: set NSTabView's tabViewType property to one of the NSNoTabs enum type. In IB it should be under the 'Style' drop down menu.

Comment: @rocky That's not sufficient because he's using an `NSTabViewController`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're using an `NSTabViewController`. You need to make two changes in your storyboard.

First, select the tab view controller and set its Style to “Unspecified”:

[image: tab view controller style]

Next, select the tab view under the tab view controller (it'll probably be named “Top Tab View”) and set its Style to “Tabless”:

[image: tab view style]

Comment: Perfectly explained!

Comment: my app have 3 tabs and 3 buttons, how to handle tab selection using buttons in tab less tabviewcontroller